# Oracle REGEX_SUBSTR , extract number from string

Tags: sql, regex

I have strings such as:

1. FR_OTC 0 THB Local 10GB 10400601 15Days T2T
2. FR_OTC 0 THB Local 10GB 1Day T2T

Requirement is to extract the number of days [ from **15**Days or **1**Day  ].
I tried working with regexp_substr(str,'[(0-9)]+[?=Days]'). However the output is coming as 15D or 1D.

Comment: Try `regexp_substr(str,'(\d+)Day', 1, 1, 'c', 1)`

Comment: Thanks. This works ! Do you mind explaining me the solution ?

Comment: This task really depends on the DBMS you're currently using, as long as syntax and existence of specific functions vary a lot across databases. Consider adding the corresponding dbms tag to your post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```sql
regexp_substr('FR_OTC 0 THB Local 10GB 1Day T2T','(\d+)Day', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

The `(\d+)Day` captures one or more digits before `Day` string, and the last `1` argument tells the `regexp_substr` to return that group 1 value.

The `'c'` option can be used instead of `NULL` if you know `Day` must be matched in a case-sensitive way.